# How to share HttpContext.Identity between Webforms App and AspNetCore Sub-Application

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, webforms, httpcontext

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application that runs in IIS.  I want to deploy an AspNetCore application as a sub-application to the aforementioned one.  The AspNetCore application uses AspNetCore Identity.  I expect to authenticate users using the primary application or the sub-application and have both applications have access to HttpContext.Identity so that users are authenticated in both the primary application and the sub-application.

I suppose a more concise question could be: Is HttpContext.Identity shared between applications and their sub-applications in IIS?

Comment: I had some similar type of requirement. we had authenticate user from Identity server with JWT token and store that token in cookie and further same token we used to authenticate in both application to authenticate and authorize.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is possible. You will need to setup a shared location for storing the keys.
Checkout this article: https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.CookieSharing and this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-authentication-cookies-with-aspnet-core-identity

I ended up using Redis as the shared location but you could just use a shared folder.

On the .Net Core 3.1 webapp you will need the following on startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.1.96:6379");
        IDataProtector proc = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\test\core"), (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName("MyApp").ProtectKeysWithDpapi().DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis); })
    .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2");

                    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(proc);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                Domain = "localhost",
                Name = ".SSO",
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None,
                IsEssential = true,
            };

        });
```

make sure you have `app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();` on `public void configure()`.

Then on the ASP.NET 4.8 Web Forms app you will need the following on startup.cs

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        CookieAuthenticationOptions opt = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();
        opt.AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType;// "Identity.Application";
        opt.CookieName = ".SSO";
        opt.CookieDomain = "localhost";
        opt.SlidingExpiration = true;

        ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.1.96:6379");
        IDataProtector proc = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\test\core"), buildAction => 
            buildAction.SetApplicationName("MyApp").SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(9000)).ProtectKeysWithDpapi().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis)).CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2");

        DataProtectorShim shim = new DataProtectorShim(proc);

        opt.TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(shim);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(opt);
    }
```